# columna no encontrada

Tags: java, base-de-datos

Tengo un problema - me sale un mensaje de error:

> "java.sql.SQLException:Column 'cod_pro'nod found."

¿Porqué sale este error de "columna no encontrada"?

---

Este es mi código:

```
void generarNumeroFactura(){
String sql ="SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(cod_pro)+1 FROM tickets";
Conectar cc= new Conectar();
Connection cn = cc.conexion();
try {
    java.sql.Statement st = cn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
    while(rs.next()){
        //Aca le digo que muestre el valor en un JtextFiel
        txtcod1.setText(rs.getString("cod_pro"));

    }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    // NOTA: So hubo error muestra el error
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

Comment: esa columna no existe en esa tabla. no hay mucho mas que podamos hacer por vos si no pones algo mas en la pregunta

Comment: Se que la columna no existe pero porque? si hago la consulta a mi bd SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(cod_pro)+1 FROM tickets con esto y si funciona, pero cuando capturo en mi jtextfield me sale ese mensaje.

Comment: y estas seguro que es la misma base de datos?

Comment: si no tengo duda

Comment: ahhhhhhh.. tu columna no se llama cod_pro una vez ejecutado el query. Una vez que lo ejecutas, como le estas ejecutando una funcion sobre ella y sumando algo, el manejador de DB le cambio el nombre. ni idea que nombre le puso, pero prueba hacer SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(cod_pro)+1  AS cod_pro FROM tickets

Comment: y tu problema no es ni de netbeans (que no tiene nada que ver) y no es java tampoco (que podria estar relacionado) es de la base de datos, o del driver que usas para conectarte a la DB.

Comment: tenias razon me falto poner el AS cod_pro gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se puede dar en dos partes de tu codigo. Como bien decis, el problema esta en tu consulta. Sin embargo, por como esta estructurado tu try, es dificil decir en que parte.

En los comentarios, especificaste que la query anda bien. Por lo tanto, el problema no es la query en si, si no el resultado.

Al hacer esto:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(cod_pro)+1 FROM tickets
```

La columna resultante de esa consulta no se llama cod_pro. El nombre de esa columna, puede ser cualquiera que la base de datos le ponga. Eso es porque estas usando una funcion para calcular dicha columna. Lo mismo pasaria, si sumaras dos columnas o hicieras cualquier otra cosa con tus columnas.

Para solucionar esto, necesitas ponerle un nombre a tu columna usando el AS.

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(cod_pro)+1 AS cod_pro FROM tickets
```